# MYSQL Query Error - Check User in Database

Tags: php, mysql

I trying to check if a username is already in use in my db but it's not echoing anything (blank page when i run )  , i want to get a true or false response

```
<?php

 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 

 mysql_select_db("data1") or die(mysql_error()); 


$usercheck = "john";

    $sanitizeduser= filter_var($usercheck, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);

    $check = mysql_query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = $sanitizeduser)");

    echo $check;

?>
```

Comment: Change mysql, to mysqli and see my answer below

Comment: any way to just get a true/false response . It user exists - $check = false ; else $check = true;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have shuffled with `mysqli_query` and `mysql_` functions

Try this,

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","data1") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
$usercheck = "john";

$sanitizeduser= filter_var($usercheck, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);

$result = $link->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '".$sanitizeduser."' ");

$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;    
if($row_cnt>0){     
    echo "User Exists"; // echo 1;
}else{      
    echo "No User found"; //echo 0;
}
```

Comment: `jsfiddle` -Only to test your JavaScript, CSS, HTML or CoffeeScript, not php!. BTW, you can use `phpfiddle`

Comment: tried the code above - seems to work - any way to check if result is true or false . I tried to echo result - got an error message (cannot convert to string)

Comment: To retrieve the results, You need use ex: `mysqli_fecth_array()` function

Comment: its not possible to stick with mysql - it has better syntax (edited code in the main post ) - just need a true/false whether the user exists or not

Comment: Returns `FALSE` on Query failure and return `TRUE` for successful queries, it doesn't mean user exist or not!!

Comment: @John_Nil, I have updated my answer, Use that, it helps!

Comment: by the way , is there any way to integrate that in a jquery function ?  I have a predefined one to check for valid email , names etc...

Comment: You need to use `$.ajax` jquery functions and call this page and fetch the result, based on the result you can show the message`http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584682/integrate-a-php-function-with-jquery-check-if-user-already-exists-in-db

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing mysql and mysqli:

So your problem is just a typo, just change the function name:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password","data1"); 

if (!$link){
    // error handling goes here: mysqli_error()
}
$usercheck = "john";

$sanitizeduser= filter_var($usercheck, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);

$check = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = $sanitizeduser) as check");
?>
```

Also to display the result you can't just use `echo $check`, you will have to use something like `mysqli_fecth_array` for example. [See the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php#112689)

Example:

```
while($row = mysqli_fecth_array($check)) {
  echo $row["check"] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\folder\checkuser.php on line 5 .

Comment: this line ; mysqli_select_db("data1") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: @John_Nil you are right, see my update, you will have to pass the connection object to your select_db statement. or even better, pass your db name in the connection

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\folder\checkuser.php on line 12

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\folder\checkuser.php on line 15

Comment: Ok, i updated my code. the mysqli_query function takes two parameters, the connection object, and the query. Here is what I suggest, When you have an error like this, just look at the function name in the manual.